# cloning element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, clone

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvas.width = 900
        canvas.height = 600
        canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#d9d9d9'
        
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
       
            
        //defining the moving square
        var RADIUS = 7
        var SPEED = 1.5
        //startposition
        let pos = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 1]
        //coordinates
        let direction = [0, 1]
        
        //defining what will happen if the square touches the borderlines 
        setInterval(function() {
            if(pos[0] <= RADIUS || pos[0] >= canvas.width - RADIUS ||
            pos[1] <= RADIUS || pos[1] >= canvas.height - RADIUS) {
                pos =[Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 600) + 1]
            }

            pos[0] += direction[0] * SPEED
            pos[1] += direction[1] * SPEED
            
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.fillStyle = "#6666ff"
            ctx.fillRect(pos[0] - RADIUS, pos[1] - RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS, 2 * RADIUS)
        }, 20)
        
        

        setInterval(function() {
            const randomAngle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI
            direction = [Math.cos(randomAngle), Math.sin(randomAngle)]
        }, 500)
```

So I have this Code and now want that the box that moves around can duplicate after lets say 15 seconds. also the duplication also has to duplicate again after the same amount of time. I came across this:

```
       var item01 = item.cloneNode(true);
```

but don't find a proper way to implement it.

Comment: Also did you provide element to Node? For example like this: `parentElement.insertBefore(newItem, oldItem)`?

Comment: no. this is all my code that I have written